# how to plot graph for list inside list in python

Tags: python, plot

I am doing Text document classification. I get output of list in list.
I want to plot graph for that output. I tried many solutions but not working.

```
[['music', 0.9997035991551619], ['clinton', 0.0002957437097329556], ['medical', 4.79185067413781e-07], ['lawyer', 1.169147467118116e-07], ['math', 6.103529098184536e-08]]
[['music', 0.9999999335021967], ['clinton', 3.6432542499586986e-08], ['lawyer', 1.9271856247574045e-08], ['medical', 1.0573808395422241e-08], ['math', 2.1959604279885474e-10]]
[['music', 0.9906586064213146], ['clinton', 0.009118108207764927], ['lawyer', 0.0001755035896399725], ['math', 3.968412986939692e-05], ['medical', 8.097651411110852e-06]]
[['clinton', 0.9997343806423091], ['music', 0.0002655904281052258], ['lawyer', 2.64804182572874e-08], ['math', 2.440138619141522e-09], ['medical', 9.028715199439304e-12]]
```

I am getting output like this. I want to plot graph for each list and inside that list i want to string as label and number to plot. I tried many things but not working. I want to use same label

Comment: What kind of plot do you want?

Comment: I want to see what percentage it have according to label. Like dot plot or normal bar chart or something